# Memory Leak for .showsPhysics

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, sprite-kit

I have just recently spent the past 5 hours trying to debug a memory leak in my Spritekit App.

After app Launch, I noticed a small climb in my memory usage.

I spent 3 of those 5 hours digging through reference material, learning about strong VS Weak with [ARC](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) (Definitely Recommend Reading up on that for Intermediates Such as myself)

Is anyone else experiencing this issue? If so is there any sort of explanation? Here is a small snippet of my GameViewController:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let scene = MainMenu(fileNamed:"MainMenu") {
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true
        skView.multipleTouchEnabled = true
        skView.showsPhysics = true

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .Fill

        //var GameSaveData = GameData()

        // Scene Config
        //scene.Landscape = "Test_Landscape"
        //scene.Area = "Start"

        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }else{

        print("Couldn't Load Game Scene")
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm not doing anything out of the ordinary here. I would Post my gamescene code, but it was all commented out at the time I was still observing the memory leak.

Comment: Can you update your question with a minimalistic exaple of code which can reproduce a described behaviour? Or you are saying that leak is happening even on an empty SpriteKit game project when skView.showsPhysics is set to true?

Comment: Hi @Whilwind, I have updated with a code Snippet. I see where you are going with this. Despite commenting out that showsPhysics line and not having the memory leak anymore, I still blame my code. I opened up a blank project and from what I can tell, there is no memory leak. It is just odd, because after commenting everything out, aside from a few comments, my GameViewController is basically the Hello World template. Perhaps it may be something to do with my build settings... Which I don't think I ever messed with...

Answer (score 8):

Eventually, out of fustration, I just started commenting lines of code, then building and profiling until the memory leak was solved.

Turns out in my GameViewController.swift file,

```
skView.showsPhysics = true
```

was the culprit. This must be somewhat of a new bug seeing as how I haven't seen this issue in < IOS 9.2

Answer (score 3):

```
skView.showsFPS = true
skView.showsNodeCount = true
skView.showsPhysics = true
```

Will leak memory by at least .3 MB/s.

Furthermore...

```
skView.showsFields = true
```

[image]

Leaks memory at a rate of 30-40 MB/s. Bad, Apple!