# Sprite Kit application hangs up

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Trying to make my first Swift app using the Sprite Kit.
The app has to create up to 5 objects that have to move across the screen randomly. The speed increases and size decreases every 5 seconds.
The scene setups correctly, objects appear and move but after some time the CPU usage becomes 100%, FPS falls to 0 and app hangs up. Sometimes it continues to work for some seconds, sometimes it doesn't.
What is the reason?

I'm just noob in Xcode - is it possible to find what block of code is working now during the simulation?

Here is the update function. I didn't include `didMoveToView` and `touchesBegan` part cause they seem not influencing the problem.

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    if (currentTime-oldTime)>1 {
        if arrayofAims.isEmpty==false {
            for currentAim in arrayofAims {
                repeat {xvelocity=(Int(arc4random())%3 - 1) * aimSpeedX} while xvelocity == 0
                repeat {yvelocity=(Int(arc4random())%3 - 1) * aimSpeedX} while yvelocity == 0
                currentAim.physicsBody?.applyForce(CGVectorMake (CGFloat(xvelocity), CGFloat(yvelocity)))
                }
            }
        oldTime=currentTime
        timecount+=1
    }
    if timecount>5 {
        if aimSpeedX < 5000 {
            aimSpeedX+=200
        }
        if aimSizeRatioX > 0.3 {
            aimSizeRatioX -= 0.05
            aimSizeRatioY -= 0.05
        }
        timecount=0
        if arrayofAims.count<6 { arrayofAims.append(createAnAim())
            currentAim=arrayofAims[arrayofAims.count-1]
            addChild(currentAim)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please read the [ask] section. BTW, no one has answered yet, so who are you thanking?

Comment: As most primitive way of debugging, try to remove parts of the code to isolate the problem. So start by removing the `addChild(currentAim)` line and wait to see if the issue still happens. Are you completely sure that update method is responsible? Enable debugging labels to show draws count (`skView.showsDrawsCount`) and nodes count  (`skView.showsNodesCount`). What numbers do you see there when app got stuck ?

Comment: Or update your question with minimal example which can reproduce the issue you are experiencing (or even upload a github repo).

Comment: Also read this about possible leak when `skView.showsPhysics` is set to true http://stackoverflow.com/a/34846483/3402095

Comment: you may need to post what is going on inside your createAnAim() function.

Comment: May by its some Sprite Kit collision model bug?
A had 
aim.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: aim.texture!, size: aim.size)
aim.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = aimCategory
aim.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = aimCategory | boundCategory

I replaced it with 
aim.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = boundCategory

and freeze disappeared but objects don't interact with each others

Answer (score -1):

May by its some Sprite Kit collision model bug? A had

```
aim.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: aim.texture!, size: aim.size)
aim.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = aimCategory 
aim.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = aimCategory | boundCategory
```

I replaced it with

```
aim.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = boundCategory
```

and freeze disappeared but objects don't interact with each others

Comment: This is not a good answer because you do not explain what aimCategory or boundCategory is,  and it is never a good idea to assume it is a bug with Sprite Kit,  always assume the bug is on your end until you can prove that it is the fault of the API

Comment: @Knight0fDragon you are right but I assumed that its some problem with API because it appeared at random time during the objects collisions and disappeared when the collision check was removed. The category declaration was let aimCategory: UInt32 = 0x1 << 0 
    let boundCategory: UInt32 = 0x1 << 1

Comment: @DimitryTheBlack If you upload the repo with minimal example which can reproduce the issue we will be able to tell more. I doubt this is a bug with SpriteKit and I would say that something is wrong with your code (but never knows).

Comment: @Whirlwind I'm new on this site. Whats the repo and how can I reproduce for the public the freeze of the app

Comment: I meant to make project available on [Github](https://github.com/) This is not  the practice though. Usually, you post a minimal example of code which can reproduce what you are saying, here, directly on StackOverflow. Also none of these is a must, but it can help you to getting your answer easier.